# Getting DLL error when trying to instal @heroicons/react in electron app

Tags: reactjs, electron, tailwind-css

When attempting to use the tailwindlab [@heroicons/react](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons) package within Electron I get the DLL error below:

[image: dll error screenshot]

Webpack does not seem to be able to find the package when compiling the `dll` file.

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching and this helpful [github issue](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/2438#issuecomment-616195242) that had a similar issue, I ended up implementing a small tweak of the `webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.babel.js` (that file reference is for those that used the electron app boilerplate), that tweak was needed around the `renderer` entry point.

The previous value for the entry point was as follow:

```js
entry: {
   renderer:{ Object.keys(dependencies || {}}
}
```

At [steveetm](https://github.com/steveetm)'s suggestion(ish) I changed it to:

```js
entry: {
   renderer: [
      ...Object.keys(dependencies || {}),
      '@heroicons/react/solid',
      '@heroicons/react/outline'
    ].filter(key => key !== '@heroicons/react')
}
```

I think the reason it does not work standalone is that `@heroicons` has two sub-packages within one and the renderer does not know what to do with that.